# To receive the data from two remote XBees in LabVIEW without getting mixed?

Tags: labview, xbee

I have two remote XBees each is connected to a microcontroller. The microcontrollers sample the waveforms of two different points of power system and send data to receiver xbee which ultimately is imported into LabVIEW.

Now the problem is I need to analyze the two different data streams without for example a data point from XBee 1 ending up in the XBee 2 data set.

One method that I think is to introduce some recognized numbers in sending data so that on its basis we can identity that the data is of Xbee 1 or 2. How can I do that?

http://forums.ni.com/ni/attachments/ni/170/964005/1/ThreePhaseNewwindow.vi
http://forums.ni.com/ni/attachments/ni/170/964005/2/Capture.PNG

Comment: It sounds like this is a C/microcontroller question that is unrelated to LabVIEW. Please post your C code so we can help you.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: No its LabVIEW problem. We can control the sending time of two units on sending side.

Comment: Do you need a LabVIEW solution that splits the data based on time? It would be easier to add an identifier in the C code like you said yourself. Either way you will need to add more info to your question if you want help.